# AJAX Program Not running on Webstie but working fine on Local WAMP Server

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wamp, wampserver

Well i am trying to Test the AJAX code and running the sample Example from this book :

AJAX and PHP By: Audra Hendrix; Bogdan Brinzarea; Cristian Darie

Now there are Three Files :

1) Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>AJAX with PHP, 2nd Edition: Quickstart</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="quickstart.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload='process()'>
Server wants to know your name: 
<input type="text" id="myName" />
<div id="divMessage" />
</body>
</html>
```

2) quickstart.js

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();
function createXmlHttpRequestObject() { 
var xmlHttp;
if(window.ActiveXObject)  {
try {
xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
catch (e) {
xmlHttp = false;
}
}
else
{
try {
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
catch (e) {
xmlHttp = false;
}
}
if (!xmlHttp)
alert("Error creating the XMLHttpRequest object.");
else 
return xmlHttp;
}
function process(){
if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == 0)  {
name = encodeURIComponent( 
document.getElementById("myName").value);
xmlHttp.open("GET", "quickstart.php?name=" + name, true);  
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
xmlHttp.send(null);
}
else
setTimeout('process()', 1000);
}
function handleServerResponse() {
if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)   {
if (xmlHttp.status == 200)    {
xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
helloMessage = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
document.getElementById("divMessage").innerHTML = 
'<i>' + helloMessage 
+ '</i>';
setTimeout('process()', 1000);
} 
else     {
alert("There was a problem accessing the server: " + 
xmlHttp.statusText);
}
}
}
```

3) quickstart.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>';
echo '<response>';
$name = $_GET['name'];
$userNames = array('YODA', 'AUDRA', 'BOGDAN', 'CRISTIAN');
if (in_array(strtoupper($name), $userNames))
echo 'Hello, master ' . htmlentities($name) . '!';
else if (trim($name) == '')
echo 'Stranger, please tell me your name!';
else
echo htmlentities($name) . ', I don\'t know you!';
echo '</response>';
?>
```

But the same code is showing me the problem when i upload it into my Site: 000Webhost.com

I tried on 3 Different Browsers:

1) Google Chrome showing me No Error but the code is not running either.

2) FireFox is showing this error as:
XML Parsing Error: junk after document element Location: http://flavorsofsoul.site88.net/ajax/quickstart/quickstart.php?name= Line Number 3, Column 1:

3) And IE8 is showing this:
Webpage error details

Message: Object required
Line: 65
Char: 7
Code: 0
URI: http://flavorsofsoul.site88.net/ajax/quickstart/quickstart.js

I have tried to find the Solution from Internet but nothing was helpful. So if anyone can  Provide the Solution , i shall be thankful.

Comment: If that's code directly out of the book, you should throw the book in the trash.

Comment: But how can the book be wrong, if the same code is working fine on WAMP Server locally. I am just trying to learn. Can you suggest a better book and what was base that made you say so ?

Comment: Have you checked the exact response you're getting from the server? Perhaps there are warnings in the code that cause the XML to become invalid?

Comment: I have added the Warnings or errors i am getting on different browsers. That's all i got from there. Nothing else.

Comment: @khappi: stylistically, the code is a total mess.

Comment: @MarcB. You can be absolutely right , but then can you suggest me something better to start with. I'll be great full.

Comment: @khappi You should think about using jquery for your ajax, your eventully use it anyway.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone. I have just started it. Have to learn that too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a port of your code using jQuery, It will poll each second and `$_GET` the value in the text box to the server, and dependent on that fill a json array with the name, then if the name returned is greater then 1 char replace the divMessage div with a message, hope it helps:

**polling.php**

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['name']) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest'){

    header('Content-type: application/json');

    $userNames = array('YODA', 'AUDRA', 'BOGDAN', 'CRISTIAN');

    if (in_array(strtoupper($_GET['name']), $userNames)){
        $data = array('name'=>$_GET['name']);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array('name'=>''));
    }
    die;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>AJAX Polling with jQuery & PHP (json)</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
//jQuery stuff
function poll(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var name = $("#name").val();
        if(name.length == 0){name = 'null';}

        $.ajax({ url: "polling.php?name=" + name, cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            if(data.name.length >= 1){
                $("#divMessage").replaceWith('<div id="divMessage">Welcome '+ data.name +'!<div>');
            }else{
                $("#divMessage").replaceWith('<div id="divMessage">I Dont know you.<div>');
            }
            poll();
        }, dataType: "json"});
    }, 1000);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    poll();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
Server wants to know your name: <input type="text" id="name" />

<div id="divMessage"><div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didn't have access to do that(Min. Reputation Points). Have it now. And did it. :) :)...